# Retrofit: How to send fields with Multipart request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send image or file as multipart request. But requests will need additional identificators such as Int ids or Strings. How can I send those without making specific interface for each API call? With basic API I can send these params as `JSON` file, but with `Retrofit` I have to make exact Interface for specific API call to do that.

Is there any way how to generalize this interface? I cant make function passing there for example `List<Pair<String, String>` and iterate over the list and add each param as separate `RequestBody` with key/value because Retrofit requires `Interface` to work.

Example:

```
internal interface MultipartServicePost {
        @POST("{url}")
        @Multipart
        fun postImage(
            @Part image: MultipartBody.Part,
            @Part ("reqId") extraParam1: RequestBody,
            @Part ("typeId") extraParam2: RequestBody,
            @Part ("device") extraParam3: RequestBody,
            @Part ("token") extraParam4: RequestBody,
            @Part ("userId") extraParam5: RequestBody,
            @Path(value = "url", encoded = true)
            endpoint: String
        ): Call<ResponseBody>
    }
```

Retrofit usage:

```
val client = httpClient.build()
val rBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(url)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .client(client)
             .build()
val service = rBuilder.create(MultipartServicePost::class.java)
val req = service.postImage(body, endpoint)
val response = req.execute()
```

Inside `service.postImage(body, endpoint)` I need to send extra list of params as part of that request.
I need to somehow generalize interface to send different params for each API call request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know if its working

```
 @POST("Url end point")
    @Multipart
    fun postImage(@PartMap map: HashMap<String, RequestBody>
     ): Call<ResponseBody>
```

and use like this

```
  val map = HashMap<String, RequestBody>()
  map["reqId"] = reqId.toString().toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
  //for image
    val body = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        map["Image kye like reqId\"; filename=\"FileName.png\" "] = body
```